# Get all path separately from neo4j Cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

[My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voFgu.png)

My start node is A . End node is E.

What can be the cyper query in neo4j such that I will get the result as

path one : A > b > c > d >e
path two : A > b > c > f > g > e

I have tried  :
 MATCH p = (n)-[*]->(m) where n.name='A' and m.name='E'  return p
but I am getting complete node list not the seperated one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "complete" versus "separated" node lists?

Answer (score 1):

Lets see the graph you have :

```
CREATE (a:Node {name: "A"})
CREATE (b:Node {name: "B"})
CREATE (c:Node {name: "C"})
CREATE (d:Node {name: "D"})
CREATE (e:Node {name: "E"})
CREATE (f:Node {name: "F"})
CREATE (g:Node {name: "G"})
MERGE (a)-[:HAS]->(b)-[:HAS]->(c)-[:HAS]->(d)-[:HAS]->(e)
MERGE (c)-[:HAS]->(f)-[:HAS]->(g)-[:HAS]->(e);
```

That is correct ?

Well then, the statement you wrote returns two paths ... sure, the **visualization** in the browser will show the full graph, but look at the other formats and you'll see you're getting two "rows" each containing a path.

You can **see** this by trying the following :

```
MATCH p=(n1:Node)-[*]-(n2:Node)
WHERE n1.name="A"
AND n2.name="E"
RETURN p LIMIT 1;
```

That will return only one path and the browser will show only one. It's just a matter of correctly interpreting/processing your results. This will show the second path only :

```
MATCH p=(n1:Node)-[*]-(n2:Node)
WHERE n1.name="A"
AND n2.name="E"
RETURN p SKIP 1 LIMIT 1;
```

Hope this helps,
Tom